# Dependency graph in .NET

Tags: .net, graph, dependencies, circular-dependency

In my app I have stuff like tasks, resources and locks. Tasks can depend on resources, other tasks currently running or finished and locks over resources. Tasks can also create resources. Is there some open source or commercial library, that can help with modeling this?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If "yes" then which edition? Ultimate includes various modelling facilities.

Comment: Yes, I use the Ultimate, but I need stuff like graph algorithms to properly implement.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by need "graph algorithms" -- you need to be more specific in both what you are looking for any in what way your current tools don't meet that need (perhaps a specific example would help).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NGenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/) - http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/.

It has a great graph library and implements [Tarjan’s strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for detecting cycles in a graph. It should have everything you need to model this in code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with the tool NDepend. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

It provides [code dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) and [code dependency structure matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx). NDepend also provides the ability to create [Code Rules over LINQ Queries (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Dependency code rules can be written, they can look like:

```
warnif count > 0 
from a in Assemblies where
a.IsUsing ("NUnit.Util") && (a.Name == @"nunit-agent")
select new { a, a.NbLinesOfCode }
```

Such rule can be [checked in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) thanks to the NDepend addin, or in [Reports created at Build Process/CI time](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

Notice that with these features, NDepend won't help you create a good design. But it will help you express and formalize the design you elaborate + it'll continuously check for you that with code evolution, the fixed design doesn't get rooted.